# Shell script called from PHP does not work, but it works in command line

Tags: php, linux, django, shell

I want to copy a file by shell script called from PHP.
However cp command does not work properly.

My system is as follows:
 Linux: Ubuntu MATE 16.01, Apache2 (port 80), django (port 8000), php (port 80)

Shell script is like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 cp /var/www/html/aaa.html /home/user/test/aaa.html
```

aaa.html is a web page on django and is saved under /var/www/html/ by php.
I call php on aaa.html, and I upload aaa.html. After that I execute shell script above on php.

When I input 'cp /var/www/html/aaa.html /home/user/test/aaa.html' in command line (SSH connect), it works and aaa.html is updated even the django's runserver is under run. However when I do the command in shell script, aaa.html is not updated.

How can I update aaa.html by shell script called by PHP?
I think if I could kill runserver, aaa.html would be updated.
Though command kill called from shell script does not work too.
Are there anyway to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: The command  'cp /var/www/html/aaa.html /home/user/test/bbb.html' worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for these kind of problems, it would be nice to have some more information like the error that is given. 
But 9 times out of 10 this is a permission problem.

When you are doing this over SSH, it is being done as the user that you use to log in. This one obviously has the permission to change this file.

When PHP tries to do this, this is usually done by the user that is used for the web-server (for example: www-data). You need to make sure that this user has permissions on the file.

You can do this with a Chmod, which changes the file permissions:

```
chmod g+w <myfile>
adduser www-data(or the webserver user) <the group belonging to the file>
```

This one changes the permissions to allow group writes, and adds the user to the group that the file belongs to.

Note: Possibly by changing-/creating this file over ssh, it belongs to your user and not the user using the webserver.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply!
The command worked properly after changing permission.

Comment: @user8257918 If you would be so kind as mark this question as answered then.